# How to add a button in 'TERM_CONTROL_EDIT' popup

Tags: button, popup, abap, sap-erp, dynpro

I'm trying to use the FM **`TERM_CONTROL_EDIT`** to show and edit a text.

I would like to know if there is a way to add a button in the popup toolbar?

Answer (score 2):

Not without modifying it (which I would advise against). You will have to use another function module or roll your own - it's not that hard.